# opencv python- noise in saved image via io.imsave

Tags: python, opencv

i am trying to save an image in opencv python. the image that the program is showing via cv2.imshow() is perfectly fine. but when i am saving it using cv2.imwrite() it is saving black image .then i have tried io.imsave for saving but it is also saving my image with some gray small blobs on that.
i am saving it with .png extension.i have also tried to save with other extensions but nothing works fine for me.

```
cv2.imshow('result',res)
io.imsave('gabor.png',res)
```

can anyone point out what can be the problem?

Comment: you probably need to convert back to uchar after a filter2d (just guessing from 'gabor').

Comment: @berak..yes i have applied a gabor filter and  i am giving it a try to convert it back but why it is showing the correct image in output then?

Comment: imshow silently converts to uchar inside. but imwrite can only deal with uchar images(for png)